# What is the sum of a finite series when the variable is in the denominator?

Tags: summation

I would like to know if there is a closed form way of writing this sum please:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a}{b-x_i}$$

Comment: It depends on what is $x_i$. Generally, there is no closed form for $\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}$, but you can approximate it by $\log{n}$.

Comment: If I was playing around with a complicated expression with unknowns $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and obtained that, I would consider it closed form and feel satisfied.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to rewrite or approximate this expression so that I can get the term \sum_{i=1}^n x_i somewhere in it? I also know that 0 \leq x_i \leq 1 \ \forall i.